# Forcing printf to ignore formatting

Tags: c, printf, curses

I'm using the pdcurses library and I'm writing a function which moves a line on the screen up one. This involves copying the current line and then pasting it above. The problem is that the curses function for printing whole lines, `printw`, uses the same format strings as `printf`. These lines could contain percentage signs, and so once pasted those signs are of course lost.

> The printw() functions add a formatted string to the window at 
>       the current or specified cursor position. The format strings are 
>       the same as used in the standard C library's printf(). (printw() 
>       can be used as a drop-in replacement for printf().)

A small example would be:

```
chtype p[200]; 
winchnstr(w, p, 200); //obtain the line
clrtoeol(); //remove the line

wmove(w, y-1, x); //move up a line
clrtoeol(); //erase the line
wprintw(w, p); //print the new line
```

Is there any way to force printf to treat the percentage signs as normal without having to go through `p` and inserting a percentage sign between every one? That seems a rather annoying for something so simple.

The first solution would be to convert `p` to a string, iterate through the string, and insert a `%` behind every `%`. But when I moving lots of lines at once (I'm trying to create an effect of the screen moving "upwards") this might not be the best solution performance-wise, would it?

The other solution would instead iterate through `p` and just use `addch()` to add each character separately. But would this lose performance/efficiency in comparison to `wprintw`? Or is `wprintw` simply a glorified version of just pasting each character individually? Are these really the only two options I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force `printf` to accept your string as it is, use the format specifier `%s` and pass your string as an argument. `printf` arguments are not subject for format processing. In case of strings, the bytes are simply copied over to the destination buffer.

```
printf("%s", "My string with % signs");
```

In case your string isn't zero-terminated, you can pass a length before the string to printf if you use the `%*s` format specifier:

```
printf("%*s", 5, "ab%cdefghi"); // prints "ab%cd"
```

Note that the length argument must be of type `int`.

Comment: You're right. Feel a bit stupid for asking something so simple. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `addstr()` instead of `printw()`. (`printw()` basically just parses the format string and passes the result to `addstr()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply change:

```
wprintw(w, p);
```

to instead be:

```
wprintw(w, "%s", p);
```

or alternatively:

```
waddchstr(w, p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.